# How to change ASCII table data?

Tags: c++

code that shows the whole table

```
char temp;
for (int num = 0; num < 128; num++)
{
    // implicit conversion - converts num to char
    temp = num;
    cout << num << " : " << temp << endl;
}
```

There is a code that shows all ASCII characters, I need to change for example the symbol P = 80 to P = 888

Is there such a library that allows me to do this?

Comment: What you want is a `std::map`/`std::unordered_map`.  Then you can build your own custom mapping.

Comment: You characters are no longer ASCII for values greater than 127.  IOW, the value 888 is not an ASCII character.

Comment: `if(temp == 'P') cout << num << " : 888" << endl; else cout << num " : " << temp << endl;` ?

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to make my own table and let the program work with it.
but at the same time I will call ASCII as usual just the numbers will be different.

Comment: So, as pointed out by @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica just use a std::map<char, int> and make your own mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example using a `std::map` as suggested in the comments could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {
    // a map from char (key) to int (value)
    std::map<char, int> ascii_map;

    // put the normal ASCII values in the map
    for(int ch = 0; ch <= 127; ++ch)
        ascii_map[static_cast<char>(ch)] = ch;

    // make your adjustments
    ascii_map['P'] = 888;

    // show the current map:
    for(auto [ch, val] : ascii_map) {
        std::cout << (ch >= ' ' ? ch : ' ') << '\t' << val << '\n';
    }

    // get values from chars
    std::cout << ascii_map['O'] << '\n'; // prints 79
    std::cout << ascii_map['P'] << '\n'; // prints 888
}
```